# How to prevent Deletion by the EntityManager (Doctrine Assocation)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, cascade

i got the following problem:

i've got an entity Inquiry with an One-To-One, Unidirectional Association to Customer:

```
/**
 * @var Customer
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Customer", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)
 */
protected $customer;
```

If i delete the Customer via DB Backend (PhpMyAdmin), then anything is fine: the field customer is set to null, but if i delete the Customer object with the EntityManager, then the Inquiry is also deleted, why?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->remove($customer);
$em->flush();
```

I just want to set it to null.

Sorry for my bad english, i hope somebody can help ;)

Many Greetings

Comment: Is this answer any use to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471715/how-exactly-to-use-ondelete-set-null-doctrine2

Comment: No...i already set onDelete="SET NULL". It works on DB, but if i delete with EntityManager the Inquiry Object is also deleted, and i want to prevent that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You annotate the mapping wrong.
Try this

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
*/
protected $customer;
```

Comment: No, that's wrong, i get the error: Invalid foreign key action: PERSIST.

onDelete="SET NULL" is exactly what i want, but instead of that the whole Inquiry Object is deleted.

Comment: The Inquiry object is still deleted if i delete the Customer object by the EntityManager

Comment: Have you regenerate the entity after adding above line?
If no please do as following
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
@knete

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't recognize the ManyToOne...with the change to ManyToOne it works.